# Some calculations inside .rolling() give an IndexError

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I don't know the exact value for `.rolling()`, so I need to calculate it based on the value of another column which is `df.candle`. So I would like to calculate index difference between current row and the row where `df.candle = (df.candle[current_iteration] - 20)[0]` (so 20 candles behind and first iteration (there are multiple rows with same candle value so [0])

So I though that something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/hy94jp4d7qwmv04/eurusd_df1.csv?dl=1')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# pandas settings
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 320)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1320)
pd.set_option('display.width', 320)

#
a = df.index[df.candle == df.candle - 20][0]
df['test'] = df.bid.rolling(int(a)).mean()
```

But it actually gives an error:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

So I'm a bit lost here...

**EDIT:** Here's, perhaps, a better and shorter explanation: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/b5o8o5/pandas_rolling_with_some_calculations_inside/

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback, and what happens when you print `a`?

Comment: Also, a sample input and ideal ouput would help, see this link on creating a [mcve]

Comment: `df.candle == df.candle - 20` will return False, so you don't have anything for index.

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/irmsc/pp/fml/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    a = df.index[df.candle == df.candle - 20][0]
  File "C:\Users\irmsc\pp\fml\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3957, in __getitem__
    return getitem(key)
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0                                                        ```

Comment: Nothing happens when I print `a`, the traceback when calculating it.

Comment: Sample input? I'm using a dataframe loaded from here: *https://www.dropbox.com/s/hy94jp4d7qwmv04/eurusd_df1.csv?dl=1*